# android program crashes in Activity class

Tags: android

When the flow reaches there, code crashes. Why? Thanks in advance.

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //erroneous code block starts

    Button returnButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imgReturn);


    returnButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();

        }

    });
    //erroneous code block ends

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel);

}
```

---

Here is the definition of the *imgReturn* identified at *activity_travel* :

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imgReturn"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
>     android:contentDescription="@string/button_name_return"
>      />
> ```

Comment: why do you need to call `finish()`? Just use hardware back button

Comment: This is a survey code, in order to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button returnButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imgReturn);
```

You have a `ImageView` not `Button` in xml layout.

Should be

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgReturn);
```

And initialization should be after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel);
```

As

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel);
// initialization after setContentView
ImageView returnButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgReturn);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. So first you need to set the layout to the activity with  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel)`. Then initialize Views. Also what you have is a `ImageView`in xml but you are casting it it to Button when initializing.

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //erroneous code block starts
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel);
    ImageView returnButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgReturn);


    returnButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();

        }

    });
    //erroneous code block ends



}
```

first: you don't have button

second: `setContentView` must be below `super.onCrete()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "setContentView" right after the "super.onCreate".
The set content view will set the xml file that inflate your class. You can't do anything with the UI befor set the xml file you will use.